# double pointer in C and reassigning null pointer

Tags: c, pointers

```
int** p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
p = NULL;
printf("%10d", p);
printf("%10d", &p);
```

then I get
0 and some address number

but since this is a double pointer, shouldn't i have value of p as an address? 
How can i have two values at the same time?

to be more specific,
since p is the address of the first pointer
if I have p = 32425 then it means i have address pointed to 32425
but & operator returns the value of the address
thus p should be &p 
but it is not

is my question. Maybe i am confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that the malloc does nothing (other than leaking memory) because you overwrite it with `NULL`. You're also allocating the wrong size, you'd need to do `p = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *));`. Also, it's not quite correct to use `%10d` for a pointer - use `%p` instead.

That being said:

The first `printf` will show a null pointer (probably represented as 0), because you just assigned `NULL` to `p`, and so the value of `NULL` is what you see.

The second `printf` will show the address of `p` itself. In other words, an `int ***` (a *triple* pointer) pointing to `p`. This is not `NULL`, of course, `p` has to be somewhere since it's a stack-allocated variable.

Comment: thx! is malloc(sizseof(int*)) just the same as declaring the pointer variable though?

Comment: @이종연, no, it is allocating space for the thing that the pointer variable points to (which happens to be another pointer). This is separate from declaring the pointer variable itself.